# Does The Lost Age offer a 'guilt-free genocidal attitude'?

Tags: the-lost-age

Sophie Lagacé's review of The Lost Age says,

> I regret that they do follow the conventional RPG model of offering the players guilt-free genocidal attitude (i.e., the “bad” races meant to be fought and killed without remorse, such as the Terasu.) On the other hand, it’s possible that the nuances are there, just not thrown in for a short convention demo game.
>
> ([Game Review: The Lost Age](https://mechanteanemone.wordpress.com/2017/05/27/game-review-the-lost-age/))

Is this an accurate assessment of the game's combat landscape, or is there really more nuance to its depiction of violence in either setting or mechanics than Ms. Lagacé's experience revealed?

Comment: Asking to contradict another opinion is still pure opinion.   Is D&D "guilt-free genocide of orcs?" Many people have argued for many pages about that, it's not fact, it's opinion. You'll have to make your own judgement, none of us can say how much RPG combat qualifies as a "genocidal attitude."

Comment: I think the question could be reworded, because it's not really about the violence, but about the depiction of the "evil" races, which I imagine is much less opinion based. I mean, the monster manual of my old D&D book specifically lists orcs as "evil." Does this other game have anything as overt?